# Walk HDFS using Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to walk HDFS using Python? If it's possible, how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: What...have you...tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, but I'm looking at http://code.google.com/p/libpyhdfs/ . Basically I want to walk the HDFS and add partitions to a HIVE table.

Comment: You will frequently get a more positive response if you make it appear you have applied a little bit of thought or effort to the topic before posting, even if it is just to link to the documentation of the libraries you have been looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some libraries that you can take a look:

- [libpydfs](http://code.google.com/p/libpyhdfs/)
- [pydoop](http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/api_docs/hdfs_api.html#hdfs-api)

Comment: In terms of walking file structure, which one would you recommend to use?

Comment: Well, I haven't used any of them really. But, you have the listing directory method on both of them, so you can use both. pydoop seems to be better documented though.

Answer (score 1):

[hdfs3](http://hdfs3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is based on libhdfs3 supports this

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
hdfs = HDFileSystem()
hdfs.walk('/path/to/directory')
```